# How to disable directory indexing on NGINX?

Tags: nginx

When I add parameters like `?.` to the ends of my site's URLs, it lists the contents of my directories, e.g. disclosing all `.js` files, `3rdpartylicenses.txt`, and some other files.

Is there a way I could avoid revealing all `.js`?

My site is running NGINX.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a javascript question.  This is more of a server configuration question.

Comment: Is it listing all the contents of the directory? 
What web server are you using?  Apache? NGINX? Something else?

Comment: @Everett Yes its listing the contents of the directory and using NGINX

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the specifics you mentioned, but it it may not get re-opened.  It would be helpful to also include the version of NGINX and any server-side scripting you are using on your site (e.g. Node + Express or PHP). HTH.